Faster Way To Getting Administrator Privileges Within Windows Terminal
As far as I know, the easiest way to get administrator privileges from batch Script is by calling PowerShell.
@echo off
fltmc.exe >nul || (PowerShell.exe start -verb runas wt.exe '%~0'& exit /b)
echo directory '%~dp0'
pause 

But, the downside of this method is slow.
I have several collections of scripts for getting it by calling VBS, which is much faster than calling PowerShell.
But none of them within the Windows Terminal, directly through cmd itself.
My question, how can i get it with faster loading than the script above? Of course, via Windows Terminal.

I don't understand the fltmc part here, but you're calling up here PowerShell.exe which is a much more evolved program than the small VBS interpreter. So it's very logical that its loading will be much slower. Not to mention that wt.exe is another very large and slow to load program. You're probably comparing two very different things.

@harrymc So. do you have any other options besides calling PowerShell?

Only 3 mechanisms : CMD/batch, PowerShell, VBS. Batch runas might be a fair competition to VBS.

After experimenting, I finally found the faster

Via VBScript

Modified from: How to request Administrator...
@echo off
fltmc >nul && goto :Elevated
echo Set UAC=CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)       > "%temp%\ga.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "wt.exe", "%~0", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\ga.vbs"
"%temp%\ga.vbs"& exit /B

:Elevated
fltmc >nul && echo admin || echo not
echo This Batch is "%~0"
pause


Via NIRCMD

Source: NirSoft
@echo off
fltmc >nul && goto :Elevated
set "nirapp=D:\nircmd-x64\nircmd.exe"
%nirapp% elevate wt.exe "%~0"& exit /b

:Elevated
fltmc >nul && echo admin || echo not 
echo This Batch is "%~0"
pause

